# Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP does not generate CRUD php classes for services while the previous version did?

Tags: flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I recently upgraded to Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP since I’m working on a big PHP/Flex project and thought that it would be easier to integrate the two.
What do you know? The feature that generate the php class to feed a flex/PHP service trough AMF is appears to be missing!
Time to downgrade or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's still there, but that feature should only be used for building a test application.  It breaks a lot of  best practices such as creating the connection in the class (it should be injected or retrieved from an outside class that manages the DB) and it puts the database definition info in the class (username, password, etc.).  I believe that when you use that feature that a popup tells you that it is not intended for production use.  When building a service class it is best to define your classes based off of the functionality you need to provide.

Comment: you are right, no doubt about it, but I DID have to build a test application, hence the necessity.